# Swift major mode indentation is not moving to expected position

Tags: indentation

When I type a `}` to close the `for` loop, the '}' is moved to position as shown in the screen shot (where the cursor is)

I expect it to be at the same column of the `for` keyword.

Indentation for lines within the `if` condition worked perfectly.

[image]

Is there anyway I can fix this behaviour?

Comment: Any chance you can file bug with `swift-mode`?